# Why does this JavaScript cause a page to open in a tab for Chrome

Tags: javascript

Why would these parameters passed to window.open('SomeWinName') open in a tab:

```
toolbar=1,
location=1,
directories=1,
addressbar=1,
scrollbars=1,
status=1,
menubar=1,
resizable=1,
outerWidth="+x+",
outerHeight="+
```

But if I use these params, window opens in a new window:

```
resizable=1,
outerWidth="+x+",
outerHeight="+y
```

Comment: Each browser handles this differently, and there's no way to explicitly open a page in a new tab or a new window. Even if you find out exactly *what* makes this open a new tab, your workaround will likely stop working with the next browser update.

Comment: I would guess this might be by design... it should be the user's decision whether new "pages" are opened in new tabs or new windows. Chromeless windows are usually dialogs (or popups), so will usually be opened in a new window, but if you are adding all the browser chrome back in to the new window, the browser is probably deciding that's a "page" and displaying it as such in a new tab.

Comment: I'd also like to add that in general, unless you want to FORCE functionality, don't open stuff in new windows/tabs. All modern browsers have the ability to open links in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with the fact that when you just use window.open("name"), it doesn't have the params to set up the address bar and menu bars and all that. So it opens in a new window *without* those things. It wouldnt be able to do that in a new tab, since obviously it would need the same UI settings as the current window.

Basically, the "desired" behavior from google would be to open in a new tab. But if it doesn't have enough info to do that, it does the next best thing and opens a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `width` or `outerWidth` forces a new window of a size different than that of the source window. If the `width` is the default (same as current window), the browser will default to a new tab (if the user has new tab and not new window checked in preferences, which I believe most modern browsers do by default.)

Answer (score 0):

In the w3c specs there's no outerWidth and outerHeight: [W3C Specs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

So, this works good for me:

```
var x = y = 10;
window.open ('Yeah', "toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,addressbar=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width="+x+",height="+y);
window.open ('Yeah2', "resizable=1,width="+x+",height="+y);
```

It opens two new windows in two different tabs.